# Make WP not format code, not insert line breaks in between tags

Tags: filters, wp-autop

Gahhhh!  Are you kidding?  Ok, I guess wp wants my source code all nice and formatted...

```
<a href="/asdf">i'm a link</a><ul><li>list item</li></ul>
```

becomes

```
<p><a href="/asdf">i'm a link</a>
<ul>
<li>list item</li>
</ul>
```

Ok, so it puts a unclosed p tag, that sucks, but who cares.  Also, I wouldnt care about the formatting, but when you put a (script) tag in there, it bumps it down 2 lines, so then it gets wrapped in a (p) tag of its own.

```
<p><script type="text/javascript">jQuery(document).ready(function(){  jQuery('.flexslider').flexslider({animation: "slide"  });});</script>
```

actually, yeah, again with the unclosed p tag...

This stuff is coming from a shortcode function, on which i'm running

```
function stripNewLinesPreg($str){
$str=preg_replace("/(\\t|\\r|\\n)/","",$str);  
return $str;
}
```

So... I've tried the no_texturize_shortcodes filter.  Seems to do nothing.

Comment: I'm not sure if this will help, but could you run it through [wpautop](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wpautop) and set breaks to false etc.?

Comment: Same result, breaks true or false... I guess that means it's not wpautop...

Comment: [Maybe try this code](http://www.wpbeginner.com/wp-tutorials/how-to-disable-automatic-formatting-in-wordpress-posts/)

Comment: Yeah, but then you wind up breaking plugins, etc that rely on wpautop and wptexturize.